# Use PGP Keypair for login

Tags: authentication, ssh, gnupg, pgp

I created a PGP master key and an authenticate subkey on my Ubuntu server. For a user testUserX, which I still have to create, I want him (testUserX) to use the authenticate subkey for the login onto this server.

```
sec  rsa1024/1CA56EBE6E0D128A
     created: 2020-03-27  expires: never       usage: C
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa1024/7D9558836D7E9E72
     created: 2020-03-27  expires: never       usage: A
[ultimate] (1). admin <admin-test@example.com>
```

I tried to follow a few tutorials I found on the internet to do so but none of them worked so far. I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server and my gpg (GnuPG) version is 2.2.4.

Can anybody help me out how to do that? It must be rather simple but I wasn't able to do manage it. Thanks.

Edit: Maybe I should elaborate my answer what I have done so far.

On the Ubuntu server, I exported the public key of the authenticate subkey to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
gpg --export-ssh-key 7D9558836D7E9E72! > 7D9558836D7E9E72.pub.ssh
cat ~/7D9558836D7E9E72.pub.ssh >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then I exported the private key to my Windows 10 computer and imported it there:

```
scp ferit@192.168.2.8:~/7D9558836D7E9E72.sub.key C:\Users\ferit\Downloads\
gpg --import 7D9558836D7E9E72.sub.key
```

So, question: How can I log in from Windows 10 to the Ubuntu server via PGP?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the approach is right, but maybe I misunderstood something.

The idea is as follows:

- each user on your system will be able to upload their **public key** on your server
- when this is done, you can import the key to a keyring
- then, when they want to login they first need to enter their user name
- then, the server will fetch the matching key ID in the database
- then, you generate a random challenge, that is PGP-encrypted using the public key of the user (and optionally yours), so that only the user (and optionally, you) is able to decipher the message
- the user enters the response to the challenge
- if the response matches the generated value, he/she will be logged in successfully.

To sum up, each user (even if there is just one at the moment...) should have their own key pair, and they provide it. You don't provide them with one, and you certainly don't share the same key with multiple users.

Everyone keeps their **secret keys** secret, but the public key may be (has to be) shared freely.

This is a type of 2FA, so I am sure you will easily find code samples for this task. But you didn't specify the language you will be using. Also, you are not exactly saying the purpose. 'Log in' is vague. Is the goal to log in to a website or some service like SSH ? Implementation will vary depending on the goal.

Comment: I thought about this a bit more and it will look like as follows. This server acts as a kind of "secure storage" where I will create two Master Keys and a SE (Sign/Encrypt) subkey and an A (authenticate) subkey for each Master Key. So, MasterKey 1 --> Subkey SE for PersonA, Subkey A for PersonA. And MasterKey 2 --> Subkey SE for PersonB, Subkey A for PersonB. With Subkey A, PersonA shall be able to login to the server and be able automatically to fetch his private key of SE when needed. Same for PersonB to get to the server with his Subkey A to fetch his private key of SE. Can you help me?

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you mean by login. SSH, website or something else ? Solutions may already exist for your purpose, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: To the server, I'll try to explain what I mean. I would like the PersonA and PersonB to login via SSH using the PGP generated authentication subkey to the Ubuntu server from which the Authenticate subkeys have been generated to make them fetch automatically their private SE subkeys'.

Comment: Alright. But SSH already supports SSH (for years). There are quite a few tutorials available. See for example [How to enable SSH access using a GPG key for authentication](https://opensource.com/article/19/4/gpg-subkeys-ssh) or more detailed: [How to use a GPG key for SSH authentication](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/authentication/gpg-key-for-ssh-authentication/). I would recommend to follow one of those guides for the proper and secure approach. The idea is that users provide their own keys, not the server. It's also best not to share the same key between several users.

Comment: I followed those tutorials with no success. My basic question is this. How can I create on this server two subkeys for authentication and broadcast it to the two clients which should be then able to login onto the server? I haven't found a tutorial that worked for this type of scenario so far. Can you help me with that in answer?

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to do it the other way round. It is the clients who authenticate to the server - not the opposite. Anyway, if you already created a private key on the server, you could distribute it to your clients by exporting and reimporting it (sounds like you did). But as I said, it's better to have one key per user. Because if a shared private key is compromised, then all users have to stop using it. You'll still have to adapt your PGP/SSH configuration a bit as described in the tutorials. If you are stuck have a look at the SSH logs and enable verbose mode.

Comment: Ok, I did what you recommended and generated on one of my Windows 10 clients a master key and a corresponding authenticate subkey and uploaded the public key of the authenticate subkey to the server via `gpg --export-ssh-key 0x11111111! | ssh ferit@192.168.2.7 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"` (example). However, when I try on my Windows 10 clients to connect to the server via `ssh ferit@192.168.2.7` I am asked for the normal initial user passwort. What have I been doing wrong?

Comment: Just a guess, but you may have to tweak option `PreferredAuthentications` on your SSH client. *"The ssh server decides which authentication options it allows, the ssh client can be configured to decide in which order to try them."* [Authentication Order with SSH](https://serverfault.com/a/283724/377666). See also [SSH asks for password, even with public key installed](https://superuser.com/q/201138/645522). Thus something like `PreferredAuthentications publickey,password,...` could be what you need.